# WCF Data Services Public Transport Layer. Anyone know how to use it?

Tags: c#, silverlight, odata, wcf-data-services

On the [WCF DataServices team blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2013/08/26/wcf-data-services-5-6-0-release.aspx) there was announcement with 5.6 release of the new feature called “Public transport layer”.

> **Public Transport Layer**
>
> In the 5.4.0 release we added the concept of a request and response pipeline to WCF Data Service Client. In this release we have
> made it possible for developers to directly handle the request and
> response streams themselves. This was built on top of ODataLib's
> IODataRequestMessage and IODataResponseMessage framework that
> specifies how requests and responses are sent and recieved. With this
> addition developers are able to tweak the request and response streams
> or even completely replace the HTTP layer if they so desire. We are
> working on a blog post and sample documenting how to use this
> functionality.

And a blog post about how to use the functionality was promised but it’s still not there:(

The reason I need it is to compress traffic between Silverlight client and WCF DataServices. On [Feature suggestions site](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72027-wcf-data-services-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1012617-easily-compress-traffic-between-client-and-server) the issue is now closed as “Completed” with explanation that with “public transport layer” it is now possible. It sounds great, but after long hours of searching I can’t find any sample on how to do it. MSDN documentation is also lacking.

Anyone here has some insight?